# how to receive the data from dialog fragment to activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

I am calling a DialogFragment from Activity to select the state (RecyclerView in DialogFragment).
But i'm not sure how to receive back the selected state.
I know use of Recyclerview, the main task is send back data to previous activity from `DialogFragment.`
From Activity to Activity I can use `startActivityForResult(intent, code)` , but from `Activity to DialogFragment` i'm not getting this.

```
Activity1 ---> DialogFragment ---> Activity1
```

Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred method is to use a callback to get a signal from a Fragment. Also, this is the recommended method proposed by Android at [Communicating with the Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#CommunicatingWithActivity)

For your example, in your `DialogFragment`, add an interface and register it.

```
public static interface OnCompleteListener {
    public abstract void onComplete(String time);
}

private OnCompleteListener mListener;

// make sure the Activity implemented it
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity); 
    try {
        this.mListener = (OnCompleteListener)activity;
    }
    catch (final ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnCompleteListener");
    }
}
```

Now implement this interface in your `Activity`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyDialogFragment.OnCompleteListener {
    //...

    public void onComplete(String time) {
        // After the dialog fragment completes, it calls this callback.
        // use the string here
    }
}
```

Now in your `DialogFragment`, when a user clicks the OK button, send that value back to the `Activity` via your callback.

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    String time = Integer.toString(hourOfDay) + " : " + Integer.toString(minute);
    this.mListener.onComplete(time);
}
```

You can pass selected list values by using cal back in similar way

Comment: I'm using RecyclerView in DialogFragment, in that case I have to create interface in RecyclerView Adapter right?

Comment: Yes, exactly instead of dialog fragment  u can do all this stuff in adapter

Comment: Tried the code, but i  don't know where I have done wrong I'm getting ClassCastException, and the app crashing without opening the dialog fragment.

Comment: the method in activity onComplete(String time) is greyed meaning not used anywhere. Please help where I have done the mistake.

Comment: u didn't call onComplete method in adapter. Read out last code snippet which i shared with you  (onTimeSet method in which i call oncomplete method and pass the required param . In your case it's a list)

Comment: checkout my updated comment above again i edited. Hope u got ur ans

Comment: I did in card view listener as mine is recyclerview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221442/discussion-between-ghulam-qadir-and-g-ganesh).

Answer (score 1):

you can use interface an call it in your activity

public interface OnChangeListener {
void onChange(int state);

```
}
```